# how to stop repeating a function in javascript once I try and rebuild an array?

Tags: javascript, list, function, addeventlistener

I am trying to learn javascript and want to make a todo list with a few different features. I have added a delete button dd it works successfully but when I rebuild my list it shows the previous list also. How would I rebuild the list with only the new items. I know I am missing something simple.

Here is the code.

```
    let theList = ["one", "two", "three"]
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

window.onload = build;


function build() {
  const tbl = document.createElement("table");
  for (let i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.ind = i;

    // checkbox
    const checkboxHolder = document.createElement("td");
    const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = "completed";
    checkboxHolder.appendChild(checkbox)
    row.appendChild(checkboxHolder);

    // list Item
    const listItem = document.createElement("td");
    listItem.innerHTML = theList[i];
    row.appendChild(listItem);

    // edit button
    const editBtn = document.createElement("span");
    editBtn.innerText = "Edit";
    editBtn.style.padding = "5px";

    row.appendChild(editBtn);

    // delete button
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement("span");
    deleteBtn.innerText = "Delete";
    deleteBtn.style.padding = "5px";
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      var itemOut = theList.splice(i, 1);
      build();
    })
    row.appendChild(deleteBtn);





    tbl.appendChild(row);
  }
  todoList.appendChild(tbl)
}
```

[image: on this picture I deleted item one]

Comment: When I add todoList.innerHTML = "<h2>Todays List</h2>"; at the top of the build function it works perfectly. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

This code works. All i have done is added some innerhtml at the top of the build function. Why does this work?

```
let theList = ["one", "two", "three"]
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

window.onload = build;


function build() {
  todoList.innerHTML = "<h2>Todays List</h2>";
  const tbl = document.createElement("table");
  for (let i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.ind = i;

    // checkbox
    const checkboxHolder = document.createElement("td");
    const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = "completed";
    checkboxHolder.appendChild(checkbox)
    row.appendChild(checkboxHolder);

    // list Item
    const listItem = document.createElement("td");
    listItem.innerHTML = theList[i];
    row.appendChild(listItem);

    // edit button
    const editBtn = document.createElement("span");
    editBtn.innerText = "Edit";
    editBtn.style.padding = "5px";

    row.appendChild(editBtn);

    // delete button
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement("span");
    deleteBtn.innerText = "Delete";
    deleteBtn.style.padding = "5px";
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      var itemOut = theList.splice(i, 1);
      build();
    })
    row.appendChild(deleteBtn);





    tbl.appendChild(row);
  }
  todoList.appendChild(tbl)
}
```

Comment: The initial problem was that you call the button on `window.onload`, which would create your table with items in the DOM, but on the delete, you remove the selected item from the array and create a new table in the DOM with `build()`. Adding `todoList.innerHTML="..."` removes the previous table from the DOM before it is recreated again by deleting an item. You could look into using `removeElement` to avoid rebuilding the table

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It makes more sense to me now. Im new to coding so I am trying to just go off a udemy course. Ive not covered remove element so wouldn't be sure how I would incorporate it in the code for now. Thank you for your advice, very much appreciated.